# How does FormFieldMagnet in Spray works?

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, spray

I clearly understand how easy magnets in Spray works, but all convertions and implicits in FieldDefMagnet just blows my brains away. Here is the part from the [sources](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-routing/src/main/scala/spray/routing/directives/FormFieldDirectives.scala):

```
def formField(fdm: FieldDefMagnet): fdm.Out = fdm()

trait FieldDefMagnet {
  type Out
  def apply(): Out
}
object FieldDefMagnet {
  implicit def apply[T](value: T)(implicit fdm2: FieldDefMagnet2[T]) = new FieldDefMagnet {
    type Out = fdm2.Out
    def apply() = fdm2(value)
  }
}
trait FieldDefMagnet2[T] {
  type Out
  def apply(value: T): Out
}
object FieldDefMagnet2 {
  implicit def apply[A, B](implicit fdma: FieldDefMagnetAux[A, B]) = new FieldDefMagnet2[A] {
    type Out = B
    def apply(value: A) = fdma(value)
  }
}

trait FieldDefMagnetAux[A, B] extends (A ⇒ B)
```

So when i call, for example, `formField("name")` scalac wraps `"name"` in `FieldDefMagnet.apply("name")`, but how other implicits are chosen and applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it starts as you say with `FieldDefMagnet.apply` and then goes on to find the implicits of the `apply` method and so on for the complete chain of implicits.

Roughly speaking, `FieldDefMagnet` is 1) a value annotated with 2) implicit functionality and 3) a return type from the functionality.

`FieldDefMagnet2` is just the implicit functionality with a type member for the return type.

`FieldDefMagnetAux` just offers a simpler syntax for the `Out` type-member. It could also be written as (and maybe we should do this)

```
type FieldDefMagnetAux[A, B] = FieldDefMagnet2[A] { type Out = B }
```

This structure is basically needed to guide type inference in a way that makes the scala compiler infer most type arguments.

All of the "interesting" stuff happens in `FieldDefMagnetAux` where for different types of input types the according functionality is figured out.

EDIT: To see it in action consider the expansion of `formField("name")` which is expanded into

```
formField(
    FieldDefMagnet.apply[String]("name")(
      FieldDefMagnet2.apply[String, Directive1[String]](
        FieldDefMagnetAux.forString(
          Deserializer.fromRequestUnmarshaller[spray.http.HttpForm](
            Deserializer.fromMessageUnmarshaller[spray.http.HttpForm](
              Deserializer.formUnmarshaller(
                Deserializer.UrlEncodedFormDataUnmarshaller, Deserializer.MultipartFormDataUnmarshaller))), 
          FormFieldConverter.dualModeFormFieldConverter[String](
            Deserializer.liftToSourceOption[String, String](
              Deserializer.fromFunction2Converter[String, String](Predef.conforms[String])), 
            Deserializer.liftFromEntityOptionUnmarshaller[String](
              Deserializer.liftToSourceOption[spray.http.HttpEntity, String](
                Deserializer.StringUnmarshaller)))))))
```

Comment: Main point which i don't understand is, when does `FieldDefMagnet2.apply` with `FieldDefMagnetAux` implicit gets called? When we are calling `fdm2(value)` it's a clear call to `def apply(value: T): Out` in `trait FieldDefMagnet2[T]` and scalac shouldn't try to resolve it with a convertion => look for `implicit def apply[A, B](implicit fdma: FieldDefMagnetAux[A, B])`, so when this line is called?

Comment: I edited my answer to contain a complete expansion. To answer your specific question: all of those implicit defs are called before the method that is requiring an instance of them. Those are not resolved as an "implicit conversion" but as an "implicit parameter" (which is the more powerful form of implicit usage).